# A positive Ricci curvature problem from Peter Petersen's book

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The book "Riemannian Geoemetry, the third edition" by Peter Petersen says the following on page 304: $S^k \times S^1$ does not admit any Ricci flat metrics when $k=2, 3.$ My question is whether $S^k \times S^1$ admits metrics of positive Ricci curvature when $k=2, 3.$ If it is correct, how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If a manifold $M$ has positive Ricci curvture, then it follows from [Myers's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%27s_theorem) that its fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$ is finite. But the fundamental group of $S^k\times S^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ for any $k\geq 2$.

Comment: The answer is helpful, Thank you.

Comment: @YueH Glad that it helps. You may consider to upvote or accept the answer :)